# Change from sliderInput() to numericInput() when selectInput() changes

Tags: r, shiny

It's pretty general, but using this method (see below) throws multiple warnings concerning the if statements when using it within the original code (too long to present here). So, is there any proper way to switch from `sliderInput()` to `numericInput()` when `selectInput()` changes? Thanks a lot...

> EDIT: Example was not correctly reproduced. Code returns warnings now.
>   Fault lied obviously with `value = c(0, 10)` in `numericInput()`, which of course requires a single value. Pardon my jumping in...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("option", "Select option", c("Slider", "Numeric")),
  uiOutput("op")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$op <- renderUI(
    if(input$option == "Slider"){
      sliderInput(inputId = "sip", 
                  label = "Slider", 
                  min = 0, 
                  max = 10, 
                  value = c(0, 10))
    } else {
      if(input$option == "Numeric"){
        numericInput(inputId = "nip", 
                     label = "Numeric", 
                     min = 0, 
                     max = 10,
                     value = c(0, 10)) #Single value required
      }
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What warnings are you getting? Since this doesn't throw any errors at all, it's hard to know whether a proposed solution would help...If you could figure out how to replicate the warnings in this simple example, it would probably go a long way toward suggesting a good solution.

Comment: Thanks @phalteman - your comment gave me focus again. Solution is pretty simple, see above. PMJI...